# Invalid WMI query

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

I have a server list that feeds into a function. I'm looking to query each machine and get an entire list of all files and folders. Id like to write a file to my local machine, the file name will be the the targets ip (`$computer`) and append all the data from `$userdata` into the file.

I keep getting the following error:

> Get-WmiObject : Invalid query

```
foreach ($computer in $Server_List)
{
    $userdata = Get-WmiObject -Credential -Computer $computer -Query "SELECT * from CIM_Data File WHERE Drive = 'C:'"
    echo "$computer" | Out-File -FilePath $File_path + $computer +".txt" -Append $userdata
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spurious space in your query. The class name is `CIM_DataFile`, not `CIM_Data File`.

This:

```
"SELECT * from CIM_Data File WHERE Drive = 'C:'"
                       ^
```

needs to look like this:

```
"SELECT * from CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive = 'C:'"
```

Comment: You may want to build your file path like this: `$outputfile = Join-Path $File_path "$computer.txt"` rather than doing a string concatenation in the `Out-File` statement. You may also want to export the query result to a CSV rather than using `Out-File`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, so `Export-CSV $outputfile = Join-Path $File_path "$computer.txt"` ?

Comment: No. `$outputfile = Join-Path ...; Get-WmiObject ... | Export-Csv $outputfile -Append ...`

Comment: It would be nice if I could filter on multiple extensions in the query but, i didnt have any luck with AND Extension = 'txt' OR Extension = 'doc' etc. So ended up going down the route im using now and am looking to filter the csv file post gather

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help